# How create Entity Framework with multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC project supporting multiple languages.

the tables (User,Gender,GenderTranslate) had nested inheritance 
User inherit from Gender and Gender inherit from GenderTranslate

I have these tables

`User` table :

```
    public partial class User
    {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public Nullable<int> GenderID { get; set; }

           public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

and `Gender` table:

```
    public partial class Gender
    {
         public Gender()
         {
             this.GenderTranslates = new HashSet<GenderTranslate>();
             this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
         }

         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Icon { get; set; }
         public string Value { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<GenderTranslate> GenderTranslates { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and `Language` table:

```
    public partial class Lang
    {
        public Lang()
        {
            this.GenderTranslates = new HashSet<GenderTranslate>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GenderTranslate> GenderTranslates { get; set; }
    }
```

and `GenderTranslate` table :

```
    public partial class GenderTranslate
    {
        public int LangID { get; set; }
        public int GenderID { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual Lang Lang { get; set; }
    }
```

When I get users I need to get `GenderTranslate.Desc`, not `Gender.Value`.

How can I do that using Entity Framework? Please help me

Comment: Note : this table as had  nested inheritance User  inherit from Gender 
and Gender inherit from GenderTranslate